# Static class methods declaration in header c++

Tags: c++, documentation, header-files

I have a static class that has a few methods called from its functions. As I can't add them to the header file as private functions and I don't want them to be seen outside the class I'm coding them in the cpp file. My question is, as I have to write the doc of the project, is there anyway I can add these functions to the header? (I don't like writing the doc in the cpp if it's not coding explanation).

example:

```
MyStaticClass.h

class MyStaticCLass{
 public:
 /**
 * I can write the doc here :D 
 */
 static void myFunction();
}

MyStaticClass.cpp
 void MyStaticClass::myFunction(){
  myMethod1();
  myMethod2();
 }
 /**
 *I want to write the doc of this function but in the header
 */
 void myMethod1(){
 //do something 1
}
 /**
 *I want to write the doc of this function but in the header
 */
void myMethod2(){ 
// do something 2
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "static class".

Comment: Put the code in a `details` namespace.  By convention anything in there can be considered an implementation detail should not be used.

Comment: @PeteBecker static class : class that only has static functions? the question cant be understood because of that? i can change it :)

Comment: Why can't you make them private member functions?

Comment: @AviBerger because i cant call them from the static members

Comment: I should have said: private static member functions. private prevents them from being called from outside the class, static allows them to be called without an instantiated object like your public static member functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you're mixing up the terms "method" and "function". A method is a class member function (static or not), which is what `myFunction` is. The functions `meMethod1` and `myMethod2` are *not* methods, they are non-member functions, or "free" functions.

Secondly, if you want the functions `myMethod1` and `myMethod2` to be calable only from within the `MyStaticClass.cpp` source file, then I recommend you put them into its own anonymous `namespace`:

```
#include "MyStaticClass.h"

// An anonymous namespace
namespace
{
    /**
     *i want to write the doc of this function but in the header
     */
    void myMethod1(){
        //do something 1
    }

    /**
     *i want to write the doc of this function but in the header
     */
    void myMethod2(){ 
        // do something 2
    }
}

void MyStaticClass::myFunction(){
    myMethod1();
    myMethod2();
}
```

Furthermore, if you have a class with only `static` member function ("methods") and no member variables, then it's no different from a `namespace`. So in your case your header file might look like

```
#pragma once

namespace MyStaticClass
{
    /**
     * i can write the doc here :D 
     */
    void myFunction();
}
```

The source file doesn't have to change from what I show above.

Comment: thanks for the correction :D, this is the cloosest i can get from getting their declaration in the header?

Comment: @LuisRubiera If you want the functions to be "private" and only usable from a single source file, it's either an anonymous namespace (like I shown) or making the non-member functions `static` (and declared before you clal them).

Comment: Where did you get this definition of *method* from? It doesn't exist in C++ standard. And you are wrong on *if you have a class with only static member function ("methods") and no member variables, then it's no different from a namespace*. There is a lot of difference.

Comment: many thanks, i'll go with the namespace , its gonna have the doc in the cpp but at least its cleaner than having a mix of functions